# Speed issue in Firefox after converting flash FLA file to html 5 using createJS

Tags: javascript, performance, html5-canvas, createjs

Converted flash FLA file to html 5 using CreateJS toolkit, it works smoothly in Google chrome 
but very slow in Firefox, Click Event listeners taking more time to respond also the animations, how can i solve this issue?

Comment: What is the FPS set to? Also, what kind of animations are we talking about?

Comment: Firefox Javascript is really slower than Crome, specially when Firebug is opened, but without more information on your code we can't help you

Comment: After converting FLA file to HTML 5 using CreateJS toolkit FPS  is set to 30, and i am not using Firebug, am using click event listeners to call an animation.